# Regex - Formatting url for .htaccess GET request

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am using .htaccess to redirect some requests to a file that handles GET requests.
Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/?(.*)? handle.php?groupone=$1&grouptwo=$2 [QSA]
```

I am trying to make it so that a request `info` will match into group 1, but optionally the request can be `info/some/more/stuff` where `info` will still be group 1, but `some/more/stuff` will be group 2. Basically, everything after the first / should be group 2, but there does not have to be a group 2. I thought that `(.*)` should match everything up to the first (optional) slash `\/?` and then everything after `(.*)` would put it into group 2. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/(.*))?$ handle.php?groupone=$1&grouptwo=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks, I will try to analyze the regex to see what is going on.